# How do I convert hash symbols

Tags: ruby, regex, hash

I have a hash:

```
{:name=>"testname", :data=>"[209.04, 110.97, 38.83, 234.18]"}
```

I want to convert this to:

```
{name: "testname", data: [209.04, 110.97, 38.83, 234.18]}
```

Comment: Both hash versions are identical in Ruby. Why to you want to change this? What do you try to achieve? About the array in the string, it is save to assume that the `data` string always includes valid JSON?

Comment: `hash[:data] = eval(hash[:data])` ? However, eval is not a safe operation and can lead to many malicious attacks.

Comment: i want to deploy the value with the second format in a highchart column chart .

Comment: the series block requires the value in the second format

Comment: @sudhirVishwakarma: In addition to my earlier `eval`, you need to parse it in json for highcharts: `hash = hash.to_json`

Comment: Do you need JSON as output? Could you state so in the question?

Comment: @spickermann, I don't know if it was intentional, but the value of `:data` is a string in the first case and an array in the latter.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question isn't asked well. Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages. We'd like to see what you tried; Did you search and not find anything? If so, where and why didn't the pages help? Did you write code? If so, we'd like to see the minimum necessary to show what you tried. Without those things it looks like you want us to do your work. "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/128421)" will help you understand the process too.

Answer (score 3):

It feels to me like you want to translate your Ruby array to JavaScript:

```
require 'json'

# parse the string to get the included JSON
hash = { :name => "testname", :data => "[209.04, 110.97, 38.83, 234.18]" }
hash[:data] = JSON.parse(hash[:data])

# hash look like this now
# { :name => "testname" , :data => [209.04, 110.97, 38.83, 234.18] }

# translate to json to use with highchart:
hash.to_json
#=> { "name": "testname", "data": [209.04,110.97,38.83,234.18] }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you say that you want to create something like

```
[209.04, 110.97, 38.83, 234.18]
```

you need first to decide, what data type you want the numbers to have. If you just write in Ruby `209.04`, the type is `Float`, but depending on what you are going to do with the data, you might consider to use a `BigDecimal` instead.

Here is a solution for getting an array of floats:

```
myhash = {:name=>"testname", :data=>"[209.04, 110.97, 38.83, 234.18]"}
myhash[:data] = myhash[:data][1..-2].split(/,\s*/).map(&:to_f)
```

If you prefer BigDecimal instead, it would go like this:

```
require 'bigdecimal'
myhash = {:name=>"testname", :data=>"[209.04, 110.97, 38.83, 234.18]"}
myhash[:data] = myhash[:data][1..-2].split(/,\s*/).map { |string| BigDecimal.new(string) }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't overly clear, and it looks like you don't understand Ruby's hashes and how they're displayed. Mediate on these:

```
hash = {a:1}
hash # => {:a=>1}
```

`hash` has a symbol `:a` for its key. When inspected, Ruby displays hashes using `=>` notation, so `{a:1}` is displayed as `{:a => 1}`. It's the same hash, just the second is the original way of displaying them that works for symbol and non-symbol keys:

```
hash = {a:1, 'b' => 2}
hash # => {:a=>1, "b"=>2}
```

Moving on...

Converting the `:data` value can be done many ways, but I'd do this:

```
hash = {name: "testname", data: "[209.04, 110.97, 38.83, 234.18]"}
hash[:data] # => "[209.04, 110.97, 38.83, 234.18]"

require 'json'
JSON[hash[:data]] # => [209.04, 110.97, 38.83, 234.18]
```

The data looks like it's a JSON encoded array of floats, so treat it that way.

Putting that all together:

```
hash[:data] = JSON[hash[:data]]
hash # => {:name=>"testname", :data=>[209.04, 110.97, 38.83, 234.18]}
```

At this point `hash` is equivalent to:

```
{name: "testname", data: [209.04, 110.97, 38.83, 234.18]} # => {:name=>"testname", :data=>[209.04, 110.97, 38.83, 234.18]}
```